# GitHub submodule is empty in the cloud/server

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I am working on building a custom OS using buildroot. The working tree of my project is as follows
final-project-DeekshithPatil (Main git repository) \

```
 ---> base_external \
 ---> builroot (git cloned)\
 ---> README.md
```

The link to my repository is here, https://github.com/cu-ecen-aeld/final-project-DeekshithPatil

I have modified the buildroot directory as necessary and pushed to the cloud (gitHub). On the cloud I see that the buildroot repository appears as a submodule as needed. However, it is empty.

How do I solve this issue?

NOTE: Within buildroot directory, I have tried adding git remote add origin: [https://github.com/cu-ecen-aeld/final-project-DeekshithPatil][1]
And then tried pushing using git push. This is the error I get:

fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

git push origin HEAD:

Comment: Add, commit and push the file `.gitmodules` at the root of the repo.

Comment: Hey @phd,
I did git add .gitmodules and I am getting an error. fatal: pathspec '.gitmodules' did not match any files

Comment: Thanks for the hints @phd
I was able to solve it by manually creating, editing and adding the .gitmodules file to github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to solve this by adding a .gitmodules file as pointed by @phd in his comment.

I first created a file in the root of the repo as follows,

```
touch .gitmodules
```

Next I added the following lines to the file .gitmodules,

```
[submodule "buildroot"]
 path = buildroot
 url = https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot
 branch = 2020.02.2
```

After this I was able to add, commit and push .gitmodules to gitHub. The buildroot folder now points to the url mentioned in .gitmodules.